# Mean Reverting Spread

Tags: pairs-trading, mean-reversion

I have constructed a mean reverting spread using two indexes. I know they have to be mean reverting, but when plotted side by side they are mean reverting for a little bit and then deviate and head one direction, all because of a few returns. I was wondering what the proper way of normalizing the trend or dealing with a non-stationary mean in a reverting series?

Comment: I think I got it. Detrending the data has seemed to be the best way to normalize it.

Comment: Can you reply to your own question giving more details about the steps you used to do it ? Or was it as simple as estimating the constant parameter and removing it ?